# pycurl cancel a transfer and try & except

Tags: python, pycurl

How do i cancel a transfer in pycurl? i use to return -1 in libcurl but pycurl doesnt seem to like that ("pycurl.error: invalid return value for write callback -1 17") return 0 doesnt work either, i get "error: (23, 'Failed writing body')" . Also how do i do a try/except with pycurl? i dont see any examples online nor the pycurl examples from the site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example code would help here. Judging from the error message, and grepping for it in the source code, you've set up a write callback. This is configured, I think, by CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, and the documentation for that says:

> Return the number of bytes actually
>   taken care of. If that amount differs
>   from the amount passed to your
>   function, it'll signal an error to the
>   library and it will abort the transfer
>   and return CURLE_WRITE_ERROR.

The pycurl wrapper code checks that the value is between 0 and the number passed to it. That's why -1 failed, and why 0, triggers CURLE_WRITE_ERROR, raises the "failed writing body" exception. The pycurl code is:

```
 /* run callback */
 arglist = Py_BuildValue("(s#)", ptr, total_size);
 if (arglist == NULL)
     goto verbose_error;
 result = PyEval_CallObject(cb, arglist);
 Py_DECREF(arglist);
 if (result == NULL)
     goto verbose_error;

 /* handle result */
 if (result == Py_None) {
     ret = total_size;           /* None means success */
 }
 else if (PyInt_Check(result)) {
     long obj_size = PyInt_AsLong(result);
     if (obj_size < 0 || obj_size > total_size) {
         PyErr_Format(ErrorObject, "invalid return value for write callback %ld %ld", (long)obj_size, (long)total_size);
         goto verbose_error;
     }
     ret = (size_t) obj_size;    /* success */
 }
 else if (PyLong_Check(result)) {
      ... identical code for Long ...
 }
 else {
     PyErr_SetString(ErrorObject, "write callback must return int or None");
     goto verbose_error;
 }
```

I don't see any way in pycurl for this function to support another return value. There might be other ways, like setting up a progress callback, which does seem to allow aborts.

The relevant code in curl itself is:

```
/* If the previous block of data ended with CR and this block of data is
   just a NL, then the length might be zero */
if(len) {
  wrote = data->set.fwrite_func(ptr, 1, len, data->set.out);
}
else {
  wrote = len;
}

if(CURL_WRITEFUNC_PAUSE == wrote)
  return pausewrite(data, type, ptr, len);

if(wrote != len) {
  failf(data, "Failed writing body (%d != %d)", (int)wrote, (int)len);
  return CURLE_WRITE_ERROR;
}
```

so you can see that pycurl does not support returning the CURL_WRITEFUNC_PAUSE which curl itself allows. You can also see that curl has no way to support aborts through the write callback function. You will have to use something else.